# Deployment of MS Bot on Azure for testing taking too much time

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot

I have got a microsoft bot build using the botframework-sdk in python. It is deployed on Azure and interacted with using the teams channel. I had set up github continuous deployment but it takes around 10 minutes to just deploy it. Since, I can't test my code in emulator as it doesn't support lot of things done on teams, I have to deploy it every time I make a little code change. Is there a way to speed up the deployment?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please have a look at this doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/deploy
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: Do you have any automated testing that runs? I am using DevOps for CD but it should be similar, and it doesn't take much time at all for the actual deployment. But my build-test pipeline can take 5+ minutes on its own. If I need to do multiple builds in quick succession, I disable some or all of my automated tests so that the process runs faster.